# LIMIT does not limit the number of results - what will do the trick?

Tags: google-bigquery

Running the below query, I get output that is longer than 10 rows. when I change the "LIMIT 10" clause to "LIMIT 0" , I get empty results.
what is the right way to extract 10 results out of the returned values in BigQuery

```
SELECT
  UNIQUE(index) AS sample
FROM
  [dataset:table]
LIMIT 10
```

The result is 79318 rows.

thanks,
eilalan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your table has repeated fields and thus when you use BigQuery Legacy SQL it returns you 10 rows but then in UI they are being flattened with all elements in repeated field presented as one row, thus you see more than 10
To see this  - just use BigQuery Standard SQL which does not flatten result and rather shows it in UI in hierarchical way

So, depends on what you need - if you need original 10 rows  - you already have them they are just flattened for you in UI (see above explanation). If you need 10 rows from flattened result you need to [`FLATTEN`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#flatten) it first

But the best way is just to use BigQuery Standard SQL ( in case if index is just single repeated field (not record)

```
SELECT DISTINCT sample
FROM `dataset.table`, UNNEST(index) sample
LIMIT 10
```

in case if index is repeated record - you should specify field (for example id) in that record

```
SELECT DISTINCT sample.id
FROM `dataset.table`, UNNEST(index) sample
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: If results are flattened for display, wouldn't you see fewer rows (not more)?

Comment: sure you will see more! if let's say each row has 20 elements in repeated field  - you will get 200 rows in result if using BigQuery Legacy SQL

Comment: Changed the query to standard SQL (works fine):
SELECT
  distinct(index) AS sample
FROM
  `dataset.table` 
LIMIT
  100

Comment: @eilalan - exactly! the best way is to use BigQuery Standard SQL! Conside voting up if answer helped :o)